# Handlebars, loading external template files

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

My goal is to put all my Handlebars templates in a single folder, as so:

```
templates/products.hbs
templates/comments.hbs
```

I found this snippet in a few places via a cursory Google search, which apparently will load in Handlebar templates in external files, which makes much more sense than putting a bunch of templates in a single index file.

```
(function getTemplateAjax(path) {
    var source;
    var template;

    $.ajax({
        url: path, //ex. js/templates/mytemplate.handlebars
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
            source    = data;
            template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
            $('#target').html(template);
        }               
    });         
})()
```

The problem is, I don't understand this function or how to use it. Why is the whole function wrapped in parentheses and then made a function call? e.g. `(function x() { ... })()` I don't know what this is doing.

And if I'm not mistaken, looks like `$('#target')` is hardcoded when it shouldn't be. Furthermore, isn't this supposed to set a `data` variable somewhere so the variables referenced in the template will work?? Seems the correct function should be:

```
function getTemplateAjax(path, target, jsonData) {
  var source;
  var template;

  $.ajax({
    url: path, //ex. js/templates/mytemplate.handlebars
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      source    = data;
      template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
      $(target).html(template(jsonData));
    }               
  });         
}
```

Side note: if someone could point me to a better template engine, one that actually natively supports external template files, and is better organized than Handlebars, I'd be eternally grateful.

Another issue: I can't actually name my files `mytemplate.hbs`, because when the Ajax call happens, it sees it as a binary file and it comes through as binary. I suppose this is an issue of setting the server's mime type for .hbs to text/html or text/plain, but the issue is that this is a Grunt server and I'm not sure how to change its mime types.

Comment: I had a lot of success using the `text` plugin for require.js to dynamically load template files for handlebars: https://github.com/requirejs/text

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The code is wrapped in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (*Immediately Invoked Function Expression*), which means the function is executed immediately. That's what the following means:

```
(function x() {
  console.log('hello');
})();
```

You can also do:

```
(function() {
  console.log('hello');
}());
```

IIFEs are commonly used to create a "private" scope for a bit of code so that it plays nice (doesn't conflict) with anything else.

The second function you provided makes more sense and perhaps the first one must have been just  an example.

Handlebars allows you to **precompile** your templates so you don't have to compile them at run-time. Also this way you don't have to make extra HTTP requests just to load the template(s).

For example if I have the following project structure - (*note that my models, collections, and views are all within **main.js** just for this example and all my `.js` files are in my root directory*):

```
├── Gruntfile.js
├── handlebars-v2.0.0.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── package.json
└── templates
    └── todo.handlebars
```

My `todo.handlebars` looks like so - just html with Handlebars syntax:

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<p>Created by: {{author}}</p>
```

To precompile my template I would do the following in the command line (*you have to install the handlebars precompile script first with: `npm install -g handlebars`*):

```
> handlebars templates/todo.handlebars -f todo.tpl.js
```

Now my project structure looks like so:

```
├── Gruntfile.js
├── handlebars-v2.0.0.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── package.json
├── templates
│   └── todo.handlebars
└── todo.tpl.js
```

You'll see that a `todo.tpl.js` file has been added to my root directory. I could have named it something different if I wanted to as long as the extension is a `.js` because the file contains valid JavaScript code. Also I could have specified a different directory to output it to. Remember that the `todo.tpl.js` file is the actual template that your Backbone View will use. You write your HTML in `todo.handlebars` and compile it as `todo.tpl.js`.

Now that I have the `todo.tpl.js` file I can use Grunt to maybe concat all my JS template files into a `all_templates.js` file or I can reference each file directly in my HTML like so:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="todo.tpl.js"></script> <!-- My Template for a Todo item -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

In my Backbone View, which in my case lives inside my *main.js* file, I would get the template like so:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',  
  className: 'todo-item',
  events: {

  },

  // You can grab your template function with the name you chose when
  // you precompiled it from: `Handlebars.templates`
  template: Handlebars.templates.todo,

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this;
  }
});
```

And you're done! More info here:

- <strike>http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html</strike> (broken; see next link)
- https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/compilation.html#pre-compilation
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/handlebars
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761 (*read where it talks about precompiling*)

Comment: Hey BTW, how would you suggest I use hbs during development? Obviously I wouldn't want to recompile templates after every change. (PS: I'm not using Backbone)

Comment: Personally I use the GruntJS task: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars  -  Gulp is another option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars

Comment: @istos Wow!! That's a really really crazy good answer..You explained each and every bit very nicely. +1

Comment: Awesome! Very helpful.

Answer (score 31):

You can read template from External file no need to put html with script tag

```
$.get('templates/products.hbs', function (data) {
    var template=Handlebars.compile(data);
    $(target).html(template(jsonData));
}, 'html')
```

Comment: One can use any other extension, and not only *.hbs

Comment: thank you Donovan - this is what I've been looking for.

Comment: Stick to *.hbs, that is recognized by, among others, WebStorm.

Comment: I've been using it that way for years. Today I discovered that Firefox complains in the console that the XML is not valid! I know the last parameter is 'html', not xml, yet. For example, he does not like that:
<li>{{applicant}} &nbsp;{{#if country}}[{{country}}]{{/if}}</li>

Comment: When I try this solution i got Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

Comment: For cross origin requests, if you are running locally, you are probably loading your main page as a file and making a request to a server on your localhost. Let your server serve your main page as static content, then both will be on same origin (i.e. localhost).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple plugin to achieve this. More information about this: https://github.com/miketimmerman/load-template

Comment: Can you please add the relevant information to the answer itself so that it will be complete and leave the link available for additional information?