# Nested Functions while Using jQuery to parse JSON through Handlebars Templates

Tags: jquery, html, json, handlebars.js

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
compileTemplate = function (source) {
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

  function parseJSON(id, data) {
    $(id).html(template(data));
  }

  parseJSON('#app', kingdom);
}
$.get('./templates/life.hbs', compileTemplate, 'html');
</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite this so that I don't have a nested function.

Here's what's going on.

1. jQuery `$.get` uses `compileTemplate` function to compile the hbs file for html output.
2. The `parseJSON` function uses the compiled template and inserts it into the element with the ID, `app`.

This works just fine, except I can't use parseJSON by itself because it relies on the template variable. Hence, I'm stuck nested and can't figure out how to fix it. If I take the template variable out of the function, then it doesn't work because it relies on source in the function. Bah, I always run into callback hell.

There's probably a better way to do all of this, but this is where I'm at after doing some research and trying to figure it all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me a while but I managed to refactor the code on my own. Thanks to anyone who was trying. Here's my solution:

```
function module(id, source, data) {
  $.get(source, function (source) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $(id).html(template(data));
  }, 'html');
}

module('#app', './templates/life.hbs', kingdom);
```

While there is still a nested function, it's organized such that it works in every purpose. This way, I can use the function `module` to pull in different hbs files and parse json through them without any extra work. Just simply inputting the ID of the element I want it to end up at, the source file, and the json data (which is being loaded by a script in the head of the page). Hope this is a useful function for someone. I am really happy with how it turned out.

Comment: Half of the battle was simply understanding what was going on in my first code sample. Lots of trial and error. In the end, the answer on this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643503/handlebars-loading-external-template-files) by Donovan S. really helped me.